# what is equivalent of FX.defer() method in javafx 2.1

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

```
 FX.deferAction(new Function0<Void>() {
       @Override public Void invoke() {
       //Some code here
         return null;
       }
    });
```

I convert code from javafx 1.3 to javafx 2.1 but i face this problem. What is solution of this problem in javafx 2.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // some code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you Sergey. I already used this code but my output is different from previous code which is in javafx 1.3. Because FX.defer() method run at call time but Platform.runLater() run at some later time. Please give me some better suggestion.

Comment: According to JavaFX 1.3 javadoc `deferAction represents an action that should be executed at a later time of the system's choosing.` If it's executed "at call time" in your case I need more information. Do you have any synchronization involved? Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: Thanks You Sergey again. My problem solved this code. I was wrong. This method is equivalent of above problem. Thanks again.